# Stop auto connect on ifconfig wlan0 up

Tags: linux, networking, ifconfig, wpa-supplicant

I'm currently programming two scripts, one to connect to a wifi network, the other one to disconnect.

The connect script works well, however when I'm do

```
sudo ifconfig wlan0 down
sudo ifconfig wlan0 up
```

The interface automatically reconnect to the network even if there is nothing about wlan0 in /etc/network/interfaces.

However if I reboot, wlan0 is not connected.

Here is my script for those you are interested in

```
#!/bin/bash

SSID="ssid"
PASSWORD="pass"

CONF_FILE="/etc/wpa_supplicant/$SSID.conf"

if [ -f "$CONF_FILE" ]; then
    echo "wpa configuration file already exists"
else
    echo "wpa configuration file doesn't exists"
    #Generating configuration file
    sudo wpa_passphrase $SSID $PASSWORD > $CONF_FILE
    #Delete the line containing the password
    sudo sed -i '/$PASSWORD/d' $CONF_FILE
fi

#Connecting to network
sudo wpa_supplicant -c $CONF_FILE -i wlan0 &
```

I think it's because wpa_supplicant is still running in background, does anybody knows how to kill the wpa_supplicant running process without knowing its pid?

***Edit :*** I confirm it comes from the wpa-supplicant running in background.
The only way I found to solve it is to call a

```
sudo killall wpa_supplicant
```

However this solution doesn't satisfy me, imagine I have another instance of wpa_supplicant running on another interface I will loose all my network connections.
Pretty sure there is a better way to kill the process associated to this specific interface.
I'll dig around.
Hope someone already had this situation.

Comment: Do you have more than one network interface currently running. If not, youbmay be better off running "systemd network restart"

Comment: Yes I also have a running interface on eth0 and I might have a third one later on wlan1.

Answer (score 1):

Forget ifconfig, it *will* start wpa_supplicant too.
Instead use `ip link set wifi0 up` or `ip link set wifi0 down` to up/down interface, and `wpa_supplicant`/`wpa_cli` to connect to network.
Example calling supplicant:
`wpa_supplicant -i wifi0 -D nl80211 -c /etc/wpa_supplicant/my_wpa_supplicant.conf`
You can set your networks in .conf file directly, or add them dynamically.
Generate psk by `wpa_passphrase`, putting output inside your .conf file.

```
network={
    ssid="TOPGUN"
    #psk="qwerty123"
    psk=f910451a8a67c0e061d1a296955ad604b4fe6fb0e442b8a997f350f434e07f00
}

network={
    ssid="TOPGUN2"
    #psk="qwerty123"
    psk=538a2337031c5308082285cee3e433c62aaf49260cbb35768eeb3e6baa2d5191
}
```

Now you can change those networks from script by using wpa_cli, like this.

```
wpa_cli -iwifi0 select_network 0
wpa_cli -iwifi0 enable_network 0
```

and

```
wpa_cli -iwifi0 select_network 1
wpa_cli -iwifi0 enable_network 1
```

Where 0 is number of the first network in your .conf file, 1 is the second network.
**Or**
Adding networks dynamically every time in your script, that way you get a bit more control on which number networks has. Just remember that those are not persistent, should be run for every restart of the system.

```
wpa_cli -iwifi0 add_network <-- this command returns number of network which is used in following commands, you should remember returned value

wpa_cli -iwifi0 set_network 0 key_mgmt WPA-PSK
wpa_cli -iwifi0 set_network 0 psk '"qwerty123"'
wpa_cli -iwifi0 set_network 0 ssid '"TOPGUN"'
wpa_cli -iwifi0 select_network 0
wpa_cli -iwifi0 enable_network 0
```

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to use wpa_cli but I always get the error `Failed to connect to non-global ctrl_ifname: wlan0  error: No such file or directory`  also I launched wpa_supplicant with `-i wlan0` but wpa_cli seems to not recognize this interface as it always gives me the same error

Comment: That message means there is no running wpa_supplicant. Check it with `ps -aux | grep wpa`. If it's not running confirm with `ifconfig` if `wlan0` really upped? If it's okay, see if `/etc/wpa_supplicant/my_wpa_supplicant.conf`  file exists. If it's okay, try to omit driver part `-D nl80211`

Comment: However there is a running instance of wpa_supplicant `root      1799  0.0  0.8   6692  3816 ?        Ss   09:18   0:00 wpa_supplicant -B -c /etc/wpa_supplicant/SSID.conf -i wlan0`. The `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf` file also exists. Also I'm never running with the -D option.

Comment: Try to bring down all the network daemons: NM, connman. There is a chance they might interfere

Comment: I though there was no more interference problems since strech ? The problem is that I use NM for my eth0 interface :/

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use wpa_supplicant frontend program `wpa_cli` to control wpa_supplicant.

1. first enable wpa_supplicant control socket by add `ctrl_interface=/var/run/wpa_supplicant` in wpa conf file, the exactly path and name can be changed according your prefer.
2. use  `wpa_cli -p /var/run/wpa_supplicant terminate` to teminate the wpa_supplicant.

Please refer help of `wpa_cli` for more information.

Comment: Hi, I already have a line `ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev` in `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf`.
However I don't have any `/var/run/wpa_supplicant` even if there is a running instance of wpa_supplicant

Comment: Remove string 'DIR' please. the correct config should be: 'ctrl_interface=/var/run/wpa_supplicant'

Comment: Did it, but still no `/var/run/wpa_supplicant`